# Angular service return undefined type

Tags: angular

I have a component that during load starts it loads a service. The service would return data (and verified through backend) but in angular it returned undefined instead.

someComponent.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
          this.someService.init().subscribe(data => { this.data = data });
}
```

SomeService.ts

```
 init() {
          return this.httpclient.post<User>('/loadData', {}).map(data => this.data);
    } // yes, request param is empty {}
```

So the question is 
 1. how do I look for if the data is being set correctly? 
 2. why is undefined field got send back?

I have tested the backend through postman and when /loadData is called it does in fact return some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SomeService.ts: `.map(data => this.data);` ← that can be omitted but that is the culprit. This effectively swaps the returned result `data` for the value of the field `data` set on the instance. If you really wanted to return what was passed in you should remove the keyword `this` which makes it `.map(data => data);`

---

```
init() : Observable<User> {
  return this.httpclient.post<User>('/loadData', {});
}
```

or if you want to alter the response

```
init() : Observable<User> {
  return this.httpclient.post<User>('/loadData', {}).pipe(map(data => {
     // alter data here
     return data; // not this.data
   }));
}
```

Finally you should specify return types on your methods so your code can benefit from type safety. I have added `Observable<User>` as the return type to the `init` method declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You need a slight modification on your service as,

```
 init() {
    return this.httpclient.post<User>('/loadData', {});
}
```

Comment: according to documentation dont I need .map to map the json fields for the User parameter?

Comment: With angular5 and above HttpClient implementation already includes the inner using of the map.so it works for you automatically.